# Sending 'Back-in-Stock' triggered emails only to first 'x' group of people for each product

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, triggered-send, marketingcloudapi, architecture

We have “Notify me” button on our website to alert users when the stock is back.
When the stock is back, the API call happens from external system to Marketing Cloud to send triggered emails (Email notifying users that product is back in stock) .
This is working fine now.

Challenge:
For example,

Say 1000 people have registered for  ‘Wooden Chair’ and only 10 pieces are back in stock.
We send all the 1000 people, 'back-in-stock' email. If 10 people already purchased it ….then 990 people are disappointed !!

How can we avoid this  scenario??
Instead we want to send only first 100 people the notification. If none of them bought among 100 people, then next 100 people and so on…..

The api call from external system is sending Customer & Product information in JSON format which is stored in Data Extension.

We have thousands of products and how can we achieve something like this through marketing cloud?  This has to be realtime through API.

Comment: I don't think I'd recommend maintaining inventory counts in SFMC.  Technically you could update SKU data extension rows via API, but having that data in JSON format reduces your "realtime" options.  I'd focus your efforts on outlining what you want the customer's experience to be and working backwards toward a solution.

Comment: Some questions I would ask:  Should you send SKU back-in-stock emails to everyone subscribed to receive them or just the first x on the list?  If one of these emails converts and inventory is reduced, when should you resume sends to the notify list?

Comment: @adam I want to send them to only X people on the list. Also we have a Stock DE that is updated in Realtime already.